# Why is std::u16cout missing?

Tags: c++, unicode, io, c++11

C++03 defines two character types: `char` and `wchar_t`.  (*lets ignore the `signed char` and `unsigned char` insanity*).

These two character are then applied to `std::basic_string`, `std::basic_ostream`, etc as `std::string/std::wstring` and `std::ostream/std::wostream`.

From the streams the standard library also defines the globals `std::cout` and `std::wcout`.

The new c++0x standard defines two more character types `char16_t` and `char32_t`.  However, the only new typedefs are `std::u16string` and `std::u32string`.

Why doesn't the standard supply a `std::u16ostream`?  Or how about a `std::u32cout`?

Comment: Why do you think it needs them? A stream is just a sequence of bytes. Does it make it less likely to write and read the stream in different formats? No. Once could write a stream with std::ostream and read with std::u16stream and the streams would just work (so there is no extra protection from doing the wrong thing). So the responcability for reading a stream into the correct type of object still falls to the programmer because there is no real way to determine the type of the incoming stream (its just a sequence of bytes).

Comment: Admittedly, `std::u32cout` is not likely to be used very often.  I can only imagine internationalizing the console output of an application.  However, a `std::u32ofstream` would be immediately useful.

Comment: @deft_code: I don't see how that is useful. You will need to explain in more details why you think that is useful. You are hardcoding the storage format into the stream yet you have no method to detect if the stream was actually created using that format.

Comment: @Martin: I don't quite understand you. Is there a way to detect the format of an ASCII/Latin-1/UTF-8 stream (in the generic, non-C++ sense of the word)? You always need to know in advance (or by using a method that is agreed upon) which format the stream you're getting was created with. In the case of UTF-x streams you can always use the BOM to detect what kind of stream you're dealing with.

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv: No you can't. That's the point. Why would you hard code the stream type based on a format. It does not buy you any safety and makes it harder to use correctly. If the introduction of a stream made it safer to use them I could see the benefit.

Comment: @deft_code: as for internationalizing console output, I still don't think UTF-32 will be of any use (whether through u32cout or cout with a UTF-32 codecvt) in the near future. All the platforms I know that support Unicode internally use either UTF-8 (Most *NIX variants) or UTF-16 (Windows, .Net, Java), or a combination of both (IIRC Apple uses UTF-16 for its own APIs, but UTF-8 for the BSD APIs).

Comment: @Martin: As I said before, with the proper codecvt facets there's very little usage for caring about the stream size. It could very well be an internal implementation detail. But there are very proper reasons to want the *serialized format* be other than UTF-8, and it's easily detectable if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Martin: At the moment there is no way to print Unicode characters to the console in C++ (there are C function, but they require C streams, of course). *Any* Unicode support for C++ streams would be extremely helpful, because at the moment there is simply no Unicode support at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was decided that implementing Unicode iostreams was too much work to be worth it:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2238.html

From the paper:

> The rationale for leaving out stream specializations of the two new types was that streams of non-char types have not attracted wide usage, so it is not clear that there is a real need for doubling the number of specalizations of this very complicated machinery.

From what I understand, the standard committee realized that serialization to wide character (2- or 4-byte formats) is uncommon, and where you'd need UTF-16 or UTF-32 you could always implement it yourself using the same old char-based byte streams, but with a codecvt facet to would convert your input to UTF-16/UTF-32, which it could treat as yet-another-multibyte-format.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the official reason.

But I don;t see the need for one.
By having streams that are of a specific type you are hard coding there usage. I would prefer streams that are generic (handle bytes) that you can then customize to output to a specific format. Like they currently work.

So internally I want to use UTF16 strings. But on output I want to serialize them to UTF8 for storage. For this I would simply expet to create a normal stream imbue it with a locale that knows how to convert to from UTF16 -> UTF8 then all the stream needs to do is handle bytes.

Having the stream understand the format on disk byes you very little. Having a locale that can convert between different formats (on the device to internal and vic versa) is very convenient.

Comment: Sometimes you would want to serialize to UTF-16 or UTF-32 - mostly for compatibility with other software (some Windows file formats use UTF-16, for instance). But I guess you could still use them with a plain byte-stream using the proper codecvt facet.

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv: Absolutely I want to be able to serialize in a particular format. But I don't think the stream should be in control of that. That is the job of the local to convert one representation into another. When you serialize a string to a file you need to know what format you are serializing it and you also need to to know this information when you read it back. This is done by imbuing the stream with the appropriate local that will do the conversion.

Comment: Hate to be nitpicky but it's "locale", not "local".

Comment: @Martin: that's exactly what I said. Imbuing the stream with a codecvt facet is probably good enough to make most of the uses of  u32/u16 streams redundant.

Comment: @Martin: so for you the puzzle is why `std::wostream` exists, rather than why `std::u16ostream` doesn't?